# How to make sure elements move only in one direction on circle using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Well, I admit that I am really really bad with trigonometry. Just for the sake of context, I will add things from the question I am referring to here.

Reference question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39429290/168492.

I am trying to build circular rotating navigation but I have landed in a pickle.

**What I want to achieve:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs2Nz.jpg].

I want elements to rotate when you click on any one element. For e.g., Menu Items Are Rotated If The User Selected Item 3:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWseu.jpg].

What I have been able to do so far. I have been able to render the items on a circular plot using `sin` and `cos` function. I have also been able to achieve circular motion when I click on any of the elements (using the code in the reference question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39429290/168492). The problem happens when I click on the last element. It marked the whole nav move in another direction and do a complete rotation in opposite direction.

Below is the code using which I was able to position elements on the circle:

```js
const count = this.slides.length;
const increase = (Math.PI * 2) / this.slides.length;
const radius = 100;
let angle = 0;

var that = this;
this.slides = this.slides.map(function (item, i) {
  item.id = i;
  item.top = Math.sin(-Math.PI / 4 + i * increase) * radius + "px";
  item.left = Math.cos(-Math.PI / 4 + i * increase) * radius + "px";
  /* I tried adding an angle component (couldn't get it to work) */
  item.angle = Math.atan2(
    Math.sin(-Math.PI / 4 + i * increase) * radius,
    Math.cos(-Math.PI / 4 + i * increase) * radius
  );
  console.log((item.angle * 180) / Math.PI);
  return item;
});
```

What I want is to make the nav rotate only in one direction. How do I do it?

Below is the code which triggers the rotation on click:

```js
function move(e) {
  const n = buttons.indexOf(e.target);
  var item = that.slides.find((slide) => slide.id == n);
  const endAngle = (n % count) * increase;

  turn();
  function turn() {
    if (Math.abs(endAngle - angle) > 1 / 12) {
      const sign = endAngle > angle ? 1 : -1;
      angle = angle + sign / 12;
      setTimeout(turn, 20);
    } else {
      angle = endAngle;
    }
    buttons.forEach((button, i) => {
      var item = that.slides.find((slide) => slide.id == n);

      button.style.top =
        Math.sin(-Math.PI / 4 + i * increase - angle) * radius + "px";
      button.style.left =
        Math.cos(-Math.PI / 4 + i * increase - angle) * radius + "px";
    });
  }
}
```

I have tried changing the sign value to only 1. But it makes the menu rotate into an infinite loop.

Full snippet:

```js
const buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.button'))
const count = buttons.length
const increase = Math.PI * 2 / buttons.length
const radius = 150
let angle = 0

buttons.forEach((button, i) => {
  button.style.top = Math.sin(-Math.PI / 2 + i * increase) * radius + 'px'
  button.style.left = Math.cos(-Math.PI / 2 + i * increase) * radius + 'px'
  button.addEventListener('click', move)
})

function move(e) {
  const n = buttons.indexOf(e.target)
  const endAngle = (n % count) * increase
  turn()

  function turn() {
    if (Math.abs(endAngle - angle) > 1 / 8) {
      const sign = endAngle > angle ? 1 : -1
      angle = angle + sign / 8
      setTimeout(turn, 20)
    } else {
      angle = endAngle
    }
    buttons.forEach((button, i) => {
      button.style.top = Math.sin(-Math.PI / 2 + i * increase - angle) * radius + 'px'
      button.style.left = Math.cos(-Math.PI / 2 + i * increase - angle) * radius + 'px'
    })
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.menu {
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  background-color: seagreen;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.center {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="center">menu
    <div class="button">1</div>
    <div class="button">2</div>
    <div class="button">3</div>
    <div class="button">4</div>
    <div class="button">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Would be great if someone can help!

Comment: Plz, don't add unnecessary tags... This question has no connection with `jquery` and `vue.js`.

Comment: Will keep it in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need trigonometry to solve this problem. It's only arithmetic. Except for the *"there are 360 degrees in a circle"* part, which you already covered.

You have a menu which rotates. And some buttons which, when rotated, should remain upright. Place the rotation of the menu in a CSS variable and use it to rotate the entire menu ***and*** to rotate the buttons back by the same amount.

For positioning the buttons, use some helper wrappers (some lines from the center, really), rotated around the point in the center, placing buttons at the other end of the line, effectively distancing the buttons from the center of the menu. The rotation of these helpers (axis) only needs to be set at the start. Once set, they no longer need adjusting. Their rotation amount also needs to be placed into a variable, so the buttons use it to counter-rotate by the same amount.

Now, regardless of the rotation of the menu or of any individual axis, the buttons, by being counter-rotated by the values in the same variables, will always stand up straight. By changing the menu rotation variable you rotate the entire thing. Also, by changing the rotation value of each axis you can create fancy opening or closing effects, should you want to. And the buttons will always remain upright.

Obviously, if you want to animate the whole thing, the moving parts should share the same `transition` properties. If they don't, the buttons won't be standing straight at all times.

See it working:

```js
const axes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.axis')];
axes.forEach((axis, i) => {
  const angle = 360 * i / axes.length;
  axis.style.setProperty('--axis-rotation', `${angle}deg`);
})
let rotation = 0; // change it to adjust the initial position of buttons
updateMenuRotation(rotation);

function updateMenuRotation(deg) {
  document.querySelector('.menu').style
    .setProperty('--menu-rotation', `${deg}deg`);
}

function rotateMenu(steps) {
  rotation += 360 * steps / axes.length;
  updateMenuRotation(rotation);
  console.log('rotation:', rotation);
}
```

```css
.menu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  --menu-rotation: 0deg;
  transform: rotate(var(--menu-rotation));
}
.menu .center {
  transform: rotate(calc(-1 * var(--menu-rotation)));
}
.menu .axis {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(var(--axis-rotation));
}
.axis > * {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  transform: rotate(calc(calc(-1 * var(--axis-rotation)) - var(--menu-rotation)));
}
.menu,
.menu .center, 
.menu .axis,
.menu .axis > * {
  transition: transform .35s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}

.controls {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.controls button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="center">menu</div>
  <div class="axis">
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="axis">
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="axis">
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="axis">
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="axis">
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="controls">
  <button onclick="rotateMenu(1)">rotate +1</button>
  <button onclick="rotateMenu(-1)">rotate -1</button>
  <button onclick="rotateMenu(2)">rotate +2</button>
  <button onclick="rotateMenu(5)">rotate +5</button>
</div>
```

---

Now, as far as I understand your attempt, I believe you want whenever a button is clicked to find the minimal menu rotation for putting that button on top. I purposefully didn't solve this problem above, as I believe it should be solved separately from the problem of rotating the menu a particular number of steps.

I advise you to try and solve it yourself.
If you get stuck, below is how I solved it. I can't shake the feeling I over-complicated it, but I also don't see a way to further simplify it:

```js
const axes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.axis')];
axes.forEach((axis, i) => {
  const angle = 360 * i / axes.length;
  axis.style.setProperty('--axis-rotation', `${angle}deg`);
  axis.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', rotateToTop);
})
let rotation = -90; // change it to adjust the initial position of buttons
updateMenuRotation(rotation);

function updateMenuRotation(deg) {
  document.querySelector('.menu').style
    .setProperty('--menu-rotation', `${deg}deg`);
}

function rotateToTop(e) {
  const button = e.target;
  if (button) {
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.axis > div.active')]
      .forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
    button.classList.add('active');
    rotateMenu(
      minStepsToTop(
        getRotation('axis', button),
        getRotation('menu', button), 
        axes.length
      )
    );
  }
}

function minStepsToTop(aR, mR, aL) {
  // aR => axisRotatin
  // mR => menuRotation
  // aL => axis.length
  // angle => 360 / aL
  // stepsFromMenu => (((mR + 360) % 360) + 90) / angle;
  // stepsFromAxis => Math.round(aR / angle);
  // totalSteps => Math.round((((mR + 360) % 360) + 90) + aR) / angle);
  const totalSteps = Math.round(((((mR + 360) % 360) + 90) + aR) * aL / 360);
  // console.log(totalSteps);
  // totalSteps as closest number to 0 (positive or negative)
  const maxAbsoluteSteps = Math.floor(aL / 2); // 5 => 2; 6 => 3; 7 => 3, etc...
  return -(((totalSteps + maxAbsoluteSteps + aL) % aL) - maxAbsoluteSteps);
}

function getRotation(type, target) {
  return +(getComputedStyle(target).getPropertyValue(`--${type}-rotation`).replace('deg', ''));
}

function rotateMenu(steps) {
  rotation += 360 * steps / axes.length;
  updateMenuRotation(rotation);
}
```

```css
.menu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  --menu-rotation: 0deg;
  transform: rotate(var(--menu-rotation));
}
.menu .center {
  transform: rotate(calc(-1 * var(--menu-rotation)));
}
.menu .axis {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(var(--axis-rotation));
}
.axis > * {
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 27px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  transform: rotate(calc(calc(-1 * var(--axis-rotation)) - var(--menu-rotation)));
  cursor: pointer;
}
.axis .active {
  background-color: #212121;
  color: white;
}
.menu,
.menu .center, 
.menu .axis,
.menu .axis > * {
  transition: transform .35s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}

.controls {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.controls button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="center">menu</div>
  <div class="axis">
    <div class="active">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="axis">
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="axis">
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="axis">
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="axis">
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="axis">
    <div>6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="axis">
    <div>7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Should work with any number of buttons, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NeerajKumar, I've also posted a Vue prototype in the original question, which you might find useful. It's a bit cleaner than what I posted here, especially the `goToTop` logic. I've also added an open/close menu feature.